# Right way to do JMS Application with MDB and Glassfish 3

Tags: ejb, jms, glassfish-3

I am new to JMS and I Wrote a Wrote a sender and receiver and it has worked fine . Now i want a MDB to be used for this. I have googled a lot for this but did not find any good website so i am summering the way i wrote. Please correct me if i am wrong and 
This is not completely working so i think there is something wrong in my code.

Sender:

```
public class MySender {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        try  
        {   //Create and start connection  
            Hashtable hashTable = new Hashtable();
            hashTable.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory");
            hashTable.put(Context.URL_PKG_PREFIXES, "com.sun.enterprise.naming");
            hashTable.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "http://localhost:4848");

            //1) Create and start connection  
            InitialContext ctx=new InitialContext(hashTable); 
            QueueConnectionFactory f=(QueueConnectionFactory)ctx.lookup("myQueueConnectionFactory");  
            QueueConnection con=f.createQueueConnection();  
            con.start();  
            //2) create queue session  
            QueueSession ses=con.createQueueSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);  
            //3) get the Queue object  
            Queue t=(Queue)ctx.lookup("myQueue");  
            //4)create QueueSender object         
            QueueSender sender=ses.createSender(t);  
            //5) create TextMessage object  
            //5) create TextMessage object  
            TextMessage msg=ses.createTextMessage();  
            msg.setText("Hello ************************************");  
            sender.send(msg);

            con.close();  
            System.out.println("*****************end********************");
        }catch(Exception e){System.out.println(e);}  }

}
```

MDB and Listner:

```
@MessageDriven(mappedName="myQueue")  
public class MyListener implements MessageListener {  


    public void onMessage(Message message) {  
        try{  
            if (message != null && TextMessage.class.isInstance(message)) {
                System.out.println("((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((");
                TextMessage msg=(TextMessage)message;  
                final XStream xsStream = new XStream();
                final TextMessage textMessage = (TextMessage) message;
                Reader xmlMessage = new StringReader(textMessage.getText());
                Object obj = xsStream.fromXML(xmlMessage);
                System.out.println("obj:::::::::::"+obj);
                if (obj != null && LetterOutHeader.class.isInstance(obj)) {
                    LetterOutHeader letterObj = (LetterOutHeader)obj;
                    System.out.println("one:::::::"+letterObj.getState());
                }
                System.out.println("following message is received::::::::::::::::::"+msg.getText());  
            }

        }catch(JMSException e){System.out.println(e);}  
    }  
}
```

1. Have Created a EJB Project, added a class MyListener and has exported that as a jar and have deployed that to the server.
2. Wrote a normal java application and have added a class MySender.
3. Run the MySender as a java program.

Comment: What exact error are you having on your stacktrace ?

Comment: I am running the sender but MDB is not getting the call